# Html decoder and encoder

Tags: jquery, html, underscore.js, decoder

I want to convert all $nbsp , &iexcl with their character symbols.
And Value which needs to be decode are inside an array .

```
A[
{ id:1 , value:"&iexcl;resu"},
{id:1 , value:"&nbsp;hi"}]
```

Is there any solution for this??

I'm using html and javascript in my project. 
Answer i want to see:

```
    A[0].value = ¡res
```

Comment: those are not escaped characters. They are HTML code. `&nbsp;` in particular serves a very specific purpose "Non-breaking space"

Comment: OkaY is there any solution for my problem??? I have added more detail

Comment: Also both of those characters are invalid variable in variable names. Are you looking for a string `value:"¡res"` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var a = $.parseHTML('&nbsp; lalala &raquo;');
alert(a[0].textContent);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String.prototype.decodeEscapeSequence = function() {
    return this.replace(/\\x([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})/g, function() {
        return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(arguments[1], 16));
    });
};


var decodedString = str.decodeEscapeSequence();
```

Comment: If you could please edit your answer and explain what the code you're showing does, and why/how that code answers the question, it could really help.